# Ambiguating new declaration of 'void visualizar()'

Tags: c++

I am new in C++ and i have a little error in this program "Hello world"

```
//ejemplo funciones definidas por el usuario
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int visualizar();


 int main() 
 {
 visualizar();
 return 0;
 }

 void visualizar() //Here is the error
 {
  cout<<"Hola mundo guay\n";
 }
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\lisan\OneDrive\Desktop\c++\EjemploFunciones.cpp    In function 'void visualizar()':
15  17  C:\Users\lisan\OneDrive\Desktop\c++\EjemploFunciones.cpp    [Error] ambiguating new declaration of 'void visualizar()'
6   5   C:\Users\lisan\OneDrive\Desktop\c++\EjemploFunciones.cpp    [Note] old declaration 'int visualizar()'
```

What does this error mean? What caused it? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5):

In your prototype of `visualizar`, you declared it as

```
int visualizar();
```

However, when you defined it, you wrote

```
void visualizar() { ... }
```

Notice that the return types are different. Did you mean to use `void` throughout?